# Responsive design in django webapp with ckeditor

Tags: python

i need help with my django web app. I been learning online and also in college but I don't know a lot of css and HTML. I added to my web app CKEditor to have the RichTextEditor, but when posting an img the website looses the 'responsive' actuality. Here is an example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq27f.png)

Any way of making this image responsive?? Please helo and thank you all for your time